# Serving a website directly from an azure container

Tags: python, node.js, azure, azure-container-service

How could I serve a website from an azure container? For each user, I have separate containers, where each container multiple blobs.

In my current setup, user connects to my server, script downloads the blob and then page is rendered (where my server just acts as a proxy for azure container).

I want to change this behavior and directly serve the website from azure container. How could I do this?  I read the documentation [on serving a website from container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-static-website) but it shows a way with a single container named `$web`. But I want to serve multiple websites from multiple containers.

Cannot I just configure my existing containers, so that I can directly serve the websites from these containers? If not, what are the options I have?

Comment: did you try azure app service for containers ?

Comment: @Aravind I just want to serve HTML pages with Javscript. Would I really need app service for containers? Can't an existing container just serve it? This looks to me an overkill

Comment: guess I mistook the storage container to a container like docker. The link  you shared has the steps. the $web is for that storage account. the site pages are served from different containers.

Comment: @Aravind Looks like `$web` can hold a single website. I want to serve multiple sites from multiple containers

Comment: You need to create folders inside $web  like site1,site2 etc. and the urls will be like  <baseaddress>/$web/site1/index.html and so on..